# Asynchronous IO - difference in Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using Asynchronous IO in one of my application, I understand MSDN says even though we use Asynchronous API, OS may decide to do so based on different other factors.

But in a very simple application that read 500mb of file (using ReadFileEx, Win64, release mode, VC++) I could see behavioral difference in Windows 7 and Windows 10. For same file Windows 10 always read it asynchronously and Windows 7 read it synchronously. Is there any big difference in asynchronous IO implementation for Windows 7 and 10?

```
HANDLE m_hFile = ::CreateFile(m_csFile.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == m_hFile)
{
    return 0;
} // if ends

BYTE* m_Buffer = new BYTE[m_ReadSize];
ZeroMemory(m_Buffer, m_ReadSize);
if (FALSE == ::ReadFileEx(m_hFile, m_Buffer, m_ReadSize,
    pOverlapped, ReadCompletionRoutine))
{
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != dwError)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
DWORD dwRetCode = WaitForSingleObjectEx(hEvent, INFINITE, TRUE);
```

Comment: This is highly unpredictable, behavior depends a great deal on how well this file is cached.  In many cases when testing this code you'll get the file data from the file system cache and the read is going to complete synchronously.  The amount of installed RAM matters a great deal, old Win7 machines tend to not have as much of it.  You'll have to eliminate the cache as the randomizer, clearing that cache is possible with SysInternals' RamMap utility.  And of course it is useful to just not worry about this.

Comment: @HansPassant We are clearing the cache using Rammap. Our read file  operation taking 3 to 5 seconds every time. One difference is we have 8 GB RAM in windows 10 machine and 4 GB RAM in Windows 7 machine.